# Mouse Wheel Anchor Scrolling on Wordpress

Tags: plugins

I would like to implement the type of anchor scrolling as used on this site [Oath](https://www.oath.com/nl/my-data/) on a Wordpress website. I have found a plugin that works when you click on the anchor links, but none so far that works with the mouse wheel or when you scroll back up.

I need a code-snippet or Wordpress plugin that implements anchor-based mouse-wheel scrolling for scrolling up and down a Wordpress site.

Comment: Can you describe the desired effect a little more? I can't see anything obvious on that site when I scroll.

Comment: The site scrolls row to row by the anchors, whether scrolling up or down. To reach the next section, you either click on the anchor link or scroll with the mouse wheel, with both having the same effect of taking you to the next anchor link. Its best seen on the desktop version. Its the mouse wheel anchor scrolling I am unable to implement.

Comment: Essentially, I want to implement smooth scrolling to the next anchor link (up or down) when a user scrolls with the mouse wheel.

Comment: Does [this plug-in](https://wordpress.org/plugins/scroll-to-anchor/) help? What have you tried, I saw some ideas just Googling for "WordPress scroll to anchor".

Comment: Yes, I tried that plugin. It implements scroll to anchor by clicking on menu buttons or  links, but what I want is scroll to anchor through mouse wheel. Other plugins I found via Google don't do this too.

Comment: This demo shows clearly what I am looking for: https://themify.me/demo/themes/fullpane/home/demo-2/#Welcome

Comment: This is a JS frontend question, it has very little to do with WP if anything at all. E.g. this could be a Joomla site and it would still be the same question. Additionally, recommendations are not in scope here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're developing a custom theme, then you could perhaps take a look at [pagePiling.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js#pagepilingjs) on GitHub. I bumped into this js library some time ago and I think you should be able to achieve the effect you've described with it.

Some pagebuilder plugins might have a similiar feature incorporated in them, but I'm not quite sure. You have to do some research on this one yourself.

But, if you're just looking for some copy-and-paste solution, then I'm afraid you might be out of luck. Unless you end up using that fullpane theme you linked on one of your comments.